# Play private vimeo videos in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, vimeo-api

I need to play private vimeo videos, as per document I have integrated oauth API and getting oauth secret & verifier. I also know the vimeo private url which I need to play. The problem is I don't know how to request to play private video in javascript. Couldn't find any supporting doc at vimeo website also. Can anyone help me in playing private vimeo videos in javascript. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a verifier, I assume you are using the advanced api : https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced.

This API uses OAuth 1, which runs into 2 problems with client side javascript.

1. It has secret tokens. These tokens must not be exposed to your users, so they must not be directly in your javascript.
2. It relies on hmac encoding, and a kind-of complex signing process. Client side javascript does not provide native hmac libraries.

You have a couple of solutions.

1. Construct your URL server side, then make the HTTP request in the client.
2. Switch to Vimeo's new API (https://developer.vimeo.com/api)

Comment: Thanks Dashron for your reply. I am getting secret tokens on the fly using oauth 2 requests. Also using a library for HMAC encoding. My problem is after getting secret & verifier not sure how do I proceed to play the video. How vimeo let you play private videos after authentication? I am using iframe to play videos.